# Awaiting reactions in discord.js not working

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I currently have a messageReactionAdd and after that it will DM an embed, that works but now i want to listen a reaction on that DM but it is just a message in a conversation so it doesnt need to listen in it. I can send a DM in my messageReactionAdd and it also reacts the correct items but when i react on the thumbs up, it wouldn't log the TEST as i did, here is my code:

```
     member.send(currentEmbed).then((message) => {
      //Iterate through the dividers
      for(var j = 0; j < dividers.length; j++) {
        //Create variable to dump current number in emoiji form
        var number = "";
        //Convert digit to emoji form
        switch(dividers[j]) {
            case 1:
                number = "";
                break;
            case 2:
                number = "2️⃣";
                break;
            case 3:
                number = "3️⃣";
                break;
            case 4:
                number = "4️⃣";
                break;
            default:
                number = "";
                break;               
        }
        //React a message with the current digit in emoji form
        message.react(number);           
      }
      //Await the thumbsup reaction **DEBUGGING
      message.awaitReactions(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === "", {time: 150000}).then(msg => {
            console.log("TEST");
        });
    });
```

Don't mind the complex for loop, that is just for reacting al possible combinations and that works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The event messageReactionAdd works on the cached messages as they say in the documentation https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd

> Emitted whenever a reaction is added to a cached message.

so what you can do is to cache your message when starting the bot in the ready event like so:

```
client.on('ready', ()=>{
   client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID).messages.fetch(MESSAGE_ID);
});
```

Than the event messageReactionAdd would work.